# PHP INSERT INTO not working, no errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a row into a table via PHP.  I have read multiple threads where other people have a similar issue but I can't seem to find the solution to mine. Hoping a fresh look will help.

A few things to note:

- A multiquery with an INSERT INTO in the same table works.
- This query exists in the middle of the code (not at the beginning like the multiquery).  When I move the query to the beginning, still does not work.
- I have tried date formats, number formats, with and without single quotes.
- Inserting into a different table kind of works (the row gets inserted, category but the date and amount are not.
- I am using MAMP on a Mac.
- There are no PHP errors or Apache errors.
- The MySQL errors are as follows:

> - 2017-12-02 10:57:50 700000b4f000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
>   - 2017-12-02 10:57:50 700000b4f000 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "ginkgo"."exptrans" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
>   - 2017-12-02 10:57:50 700000b4f000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>   - 2017-12-02 10:57:51 700000b4f000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>   - 2017-12-02 10:57:51 700000b4f000 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "ginkgo"."fintrans" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
>   - 2017-12-02 10:57:51 700000b4f000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>   - 2017-12-02 10:58:01 700000934000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>   - 2017-12-02 10:58:01 700000934000 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "ginkgo"."fintrans" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>   - 2017-12-02 10:58:11 700000934000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>   - 2017-12-02 10:58:11 700000934000 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "ginkgo"."exptrans" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.

Here is my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost:8889','root','root','Ginkgo');
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo ('Error connecting to MySQL server. '.$mysqli->connect_errno .' '.$mysqli->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `FinTrans` (`Category`,`Location`,`FAmt`,`FDT`) values ('Tenant','514 Creekview',".$gross_rent[0].",'2000-01-01');";
echo $sql;

if( mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql))
{
    echo 'success';
}else{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

This is what is printed:

INSERT INTO `FinTrans` (`Category`,`Location`,`FAmt`,`FDT`) values 
('Tenant','514 Creekview',3200,'2000-01-01');success

This is the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `FinTrans` (
    `Acct` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Clients` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Counterparty` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `RentDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `Description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Location` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Date Spent by Employee` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `Date Reimbursed by Client` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `FDT` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `FAmt` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thank you much for your help.

Sharlene

Comment: Also, the sql statement works in myPHPAdmin

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful description of what the script reported when you ran it, the steps you took to evaluate the outcome and what you found in the data.

Comment: My apologies. What I meant was, the row is not inserted into the table although the code reports success.

Comment: check the connection setting again try only server name as localhost
I checked the query o/p it inserts data into table

Answer (score 0):

the code seems to work, looking at some of those errors it could be a connection issue, or an authentication issue

Comment: I use the same connection information for a multi query above this section and that part works fine.